# animateWithDuration play sound doesn't repeat

Tags: ios, swift, playback, animatewithduration, soundeffect

I have a pulsing rectangle animated with animateWithDuration and `setAnimationRepeatCount()`.

I'm trying to add a sound effect in the animations block witch is "clicking" synchronously. But the sound effect is only playing once. I can't find any hint on this anywhere.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5,
                           delay: 0,
                           options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut | UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat,
                           animations: {
                               UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount(4)
                               self.audioPlayer.play()
                               self.img_MotronomLight.alpha = 0.1
                           }, completion: nil)
```

The sound effect should play four times but doesn't.

Audio Implementation:

```
//global:
var metronomClickSample = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("metronomeClick", ofType: "mp3")!)
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: metronomClickSample, error: nil)
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
....
}

@IBAction func act_toggleStartTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
 ....
    UIView.animateWithDuration(....
                    animations: { 
                           UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount(4)
                           self.audioPlayer.play()
                           self.img_MotronomLight.alpha = 0.1
                    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Does the animation repeat?

Comment: Does the sound play at all? And how long is the audio clip?

Comment: The animation repeats. The sound plays only once. The audio clip is just a short click: length 0.36 s, format mp3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing the `UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat` option does **NOT** cause the animation block to be called repeatedly. The animation is repeated on a `CoreAnimation` level. If you place a breakpoint in the animation block, you'll notice that it is only executed once.

If you want the animation to execute in a loop alongside the sound, create a repeating `NSTimer` and call the animation / sound from there. Keep in mind that the timer will retain the target, so don't forget to invalidate the timer to prevent retain cycle.

**EDIT:** Added implementation below

First, we'll need to create the timer, assuming we have an instance variable called `timer`. This can be done in `viewDidLoad:` or `init` method of a view. Once initialized, we schedule for execution with the run loop, otherwise it will not fire repeatedly.

```
self.timesFired = 0
self.timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector:"timerDidFire:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
if let timer = self.timer {
    NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
}
```

The following is the method fired by the timer every interval (in this case 0.5 seconds). Here, you can run your animations and audio playback. Note that `UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat` option has been removed since the timer is now responsible for handling the repeating animation and audio. If you only the timer to fire a specific number of times, you can add an instance variable to keep track of times fired and invalidate the timer if the count is above the threshold.

```
func timerDidFire(timer: NSTimer) {

    /* 
     * If limited number of repeats is required 
     * and assuming there's an instance variable 
     * called `timesFired`
     */
    if self.timesFired > 5 {
        if let timer = self.timer {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
        self.timer = nil
        return
    }
    ++self.timesFired

    self.audioPlayer.play()

    var options = UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut;
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: options, animations: {
            self.img_MotronomLight.alpha = 0.1
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Ok, I see, that´s the problem. I´m new to Swift. Could you provide an example on how to implement a NSTimer which calls the animation and the sound synchronously? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check the updated answer with the implementation.

Comment: Inspiring solution, adding the timer on the mainRunLoop. This solves my problem. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the implementation of the audio player some things I can think of include:

- The audio file is too long and perhaps has silence on the end of it so it is not playing the first part of the file which has the sound in it
- the audio file needs to be set to the beginning of the file every time (it could just be playing the end of the file the other 3 times leading to no audio output)
- The animation is happening to quickly and the audio doesn't have time to buffer

Hopefully these suggestions help you narrow down the problem but without seeing the implementation of the player, it is really hard to say what the actual problem is.